# Why does `rest` return `'(())` instead of `'()` in racket

Tags: recursion, racket, infinite-loop

I came across this program on how variadic procedures can be used to implement composition of arbitrary number of functions

```
(define compose-n
  (lambda fs
    (cond
      [(null? fs) identity]
      [else (lambda (x)
              ((first fs) ((apply compose-n (rest fs)) x)))])))
```

However, when I remove the `apply` on the last line and perform the application by hand,

```
(define removed-compose-n
  (lambda fs
    (cond
      [(null? fs) identity]
      [else (lambda (x)
              ((first fs) ((removed-compose-n (rest fs)) x)))])))
```

this begins to loop and consume all the memory, crashing my computer. Furthermore, when I tried printing out `fs` to see what was going on

```
(define removed-compose-n
  (lambda fs
    (printf "fs : ~s\n" fs)
    (cond
      [(null? fs) identity]
      [else (lambda (x)
              ((first fs) ((removed-compose-n (rest fs)) x)))])))
```

I was surprised to see

```
fs : (#<procedure:id>)
fs : (())
fs : (())
fs : (())
fs : (())
fs : (())
fs : (^C                      
; user break [,bt for context]
```

this suggests to me that `(rest fs)` evaluates to `'(())`, which is what is causing `removed-compose-n` to loop, but `compose-n` gets away with this as `(apply compose-n '(()))` is same as `(compose-n '())`, which matches the base case of the recursion/first cond clause.

Why does `(rest fs)` evaluate `'(())` instead of `'()`, causing `removed-compose-n` to loop? Or    is the reason for looping something else entirely that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood what's happening, variadic procedure semantics had slipped my mind.

The issue wasn't `rest` returning `'(())`. `rest` indeed returns `'()`. However, variadic procedures like `removed-compose-n` collect their arguments into a list (indeed, that is how variadicity is achieved, since length of the list is not fixed). So for example, for the application `(removed-compose-n identity add1 sub1)` the value of `fs` will be `'(identity add1 sub1)` and for the application `(removed-compose-n identity)` the value of `fs` will be `'(identity)`. Similarly, for the application `(removed-compose-n '())` the value of `fs` will be `'(())`, which causes the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple case where you're applying `removed-compose-n` to `add1`:

```
(removed-compose-n add1)
```

The `fs` within the body of the function evaluates to `(list add1)`. Since it's not an `'()`, we evaluate the RHS of the second cond-clause.

```
(lambda (x)
  ((first (list add1)) ((removed-compose-n (rest (list add1))) x)))
```

Evaluating the `first` and `rest`:

```
(lambda (x)
  (add1 ((removed-compose-n '()) x)))
```

When we evaluate the following sub-expression:

```
(removed-compose-n '())
```

The `fs` will have the value `(list '())`, which is the same as `'(())`. This infinite-loops because the next application will still be `(removed-compose-n '())`

Using `apply` "splices" the arguments. The second example passes in the *list itself* without splicing its elements.